# Nodejs combined with reactjs to perform restfull api

Tags: node.js

am a fresher working on nodejs. 
1. My friend is working on reactjs,he designed a UI where he can perform RESTFULL API methods.He would send his request to me to access API's.
2. Am working on Nodejs,i will take his request and send it to "Leadsquared.com" website which has APIs, once i receive the response from website,then i will have to forward the response to my friend back again.
Note: Am not using database, but just take request then send to website and receive response, send it back to my friend.
Need your suggestions and help!!

Comment: Use curl request in node js

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the http.request method.

like this:

```
var options = {
host: "your url",
path: '/yourPath?id=someId',
method: 'POST'
};

http.request(options, function(res) {

res.on('data', function (chunk) {
 //do something
 });

}).end();
```

Comment: but that doesnt work, am unable to get the details on the browser.

Comment: You will get details in node server not on browser you can use console.log() to log the response in terminal , Also why don't you send request directly to leadsquared.com  from your react app.

Comment: no thats the task because i can audit the data in my node server